# where condition like in sqlserver but with rails activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a doubt. I'm using rails 3. And i want to filter my model. Supose, this

```
class Company   
  attr_accesible :name, :description
end
```

In a sql server stored procedure i'd do something like this

```
select * from Company where (@company_name is null or name like @company_name) and (@company_description is null or description like @company_description) and (@ids is null or id in @ids)
```

The code above is an example. Is for filter propouses. Which is the proper way to build a query like that?

Thanks in advance

Hope be clear.

Comment: Not very clear. How do you want to define name, description and ids variable? And why do you need ids?

Comment: Thanks! It was an example. What I want to do is a conditional where, if a paramter filter is not null then i will filter. But i have a tree or four filter condition. That's way, in sql server, i do like above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as I understood you have  in your view form for @company with name\description\ids fields.
Then in your controller you can do the search like that:

```
@company = Company.find(:all, conditions:["name LIKE(?) OR description LIKE(?) OR id IN(?)", params[:company][:name], params[:company][:description], params[:company][:ids]])
```